# Automatically open popup of the second marker of geoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet 1.3.4

I would like to know how to automatically open the 2nd marker popup of a GeoJSON layer.

With the code below, I manage to open automatically the popup of the 1st marker but not that of the 2nd...

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
        var icon_gisement = L.VectorMarkers.icon({   
            iconColor: "#FFFFFF"                            
        });
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: icon_gisement
        });
    }
}).bindPopup(function (layer) {
    return layer.feature.properties.description;
}).addTo(map).openPopup();
```